# How to find out the number of read/write requests by a process per second in Windows 10

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance

In a performance issue on my machine. The HDD stands at 100% disk utilization and makes the computer slow and laggy. The total data transfer taking place might be as low as 0.1Mbps hence its the numerous low bandwidth operations clogging up the disk queue. I want to find out which process is doing that and which file of the process is doing that so that I can debug further since the culprit might be a file in System process.

Here's the task manager view:

[image: Here's the task manager view]

Resource monitor screen at the same time. Notice disk queue length at 50:

[image: resource monitor screen at the same time. Notice disk queue length at 50]

HDD response times in these situations goes as high as 5000ms and the computer becomes almost unusable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add first a screenshot of Task Manager, Process tab, after sorting by Disk in descending order.

Comment: @harrymc screenshots added of task manager and resource monitor.

Comment: As first steps, ensure you have backups for the data on this disk; check the SMART data of the disk; see if the Event Viewer has interesting messages; run chkdsk (without the /f parameter) and test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: You can use the [system internals process monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to solve this without having to look at the actual numbers.  Just get the filter whittled down to just the things you care about and let 'er rip.  The filter and data can be overwhelming until you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more specific information on disk I/O from *Task Manager*:

[image: Task Manager Disk I/O]

- Click on *Details* tab.
- Right-click on the list header.
- Click *Select columns*.
- Add columns for any or all of the I/O fields.